# Creating a web component from an existing vue project

Tags: vue.js, web-component

Is there a straight forward way to wrap a Vue.js project as a web component knowing that this project uses a number of plugins like vue-router, vue-resource and vuetify.

Comment: use webpack, it allows you to compile your project into one frontend file

Comment: I already did that but vue-router didn't work properly <router-view> to be speific

Comment: is it just purely frontend vue.js project or with some backend like node or php?